# OSError: Could not open VISA library

Tags: python

I have just installed pyvisa on my mac with

```
$ pip install pyvisa
```

But when I was to test it using IDLE like this:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
```

I got this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    rm = visa.ResourceManager()
  File "/Users/siyuqi/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 1488, in __new__
    visa_library = open_visa_library(visa_library)
  File "/Users/siyuqi/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 1460, in open_visa_library
    return cls(argument)
  File "/Users/siyuqi/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 96, in __new__
    raise OSError('Could not open VISA library:\n' + '\n'.join(errs))
OSError: Could not open VISA library:
```

If I try 'pip install' in Terminal again, I will get the following result:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyvisa in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyvisa)
```

Could anybody please kindly help me solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: From what it looks like, the python library *is* installed - but I can't tell if it's trying to look for some separate dependency on your computer or something like that.

Comment: some module only targetted for python3. try with python3

Comment: and looks like PyVISA is a wrapper to underlying library,   you probably dont have that library installed or it does not works on OSX.

Comment: I'm on OSX and I tried on Python 2, 3.4 and 3.5 and I got the same error.

Comment: Thank YOU. The official website of Pyvisa says it runs on Python 2.6+ and 3.2+. Does it mean I have to use Python 2.6.x or 3.2.x (instead of 2.7.x)?

Comment: No, the + indicates any version after 2.6 - so you are fine

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/faq.html#error-no-matching-architecture

Comment: @SiyuQi actually indicates: tested with 2.6 and 3.2+. So that means you should test with 2.6. However, the 3.2+ seems misleading, because the + indicates anything above that version, and it is not working on 3.4 or 3.5.

Comment: Try installing the VISA library in your system.

Comment: @SeanBallais How could I do that? I thought 'pip install' indicates installing a library, am i right?

Comment: @SiyuQi `pip` only installed the package `PyVISA` and not the underlying library that it requires. `PyVISA` is only a wrapper for the VISA library which, from what I've read, is written in C. So, you have to install the VISA library in your system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OSError` occurs because PyVISA could not find the VISA library in your system. From the PyVISA documentation itself it says:

> ### OSError: Could not open VISA library
>
> This error occurs when you have not provided a path for the VISA library and PyVISA is not able to find it for you.

This could mean that the VISA library is not installed in your system or the VISA library is installed but in a directory that PyVISA does not know about.

You have to first install NI-VISA for PyVisa to work. PyVisa is only a Python binding for NI-VISA.

[Here](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/getting_nivisa.html#getting-nivisa) is a link to download and install NI-VISA to your system.

---

If it still outputs `OSError: Could not open VISA library`, the PyVISA documentation suggests that you do something like this.

```
visalib = VisaLibrary('/path/to/library')
```

or

```
rm = ResourceManager('Path to library')
```

You can also resort to creating a configuration file as described in [Configuring the NI backend](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/configuring.html#configuring).

Source: http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/faq.html

Comment: I followed those instructions and got exactly the same error. The instructions say I'm supposed to point to "libvisa.so.7" on my windows machine. Maybe they meant to say .exe? Regardless, there is no libvisa.* installed by those instructions.

Comment: Found it! 

    rm = visa.ResourceManager("C:/Windows/System32/visa32.dll")