# Is it a PyVISA installation failure ? Or, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, visa, pyvisa

I wanted to test my PyVISA installation and got a certain failure:

```
>>> import visa
>>> rm = visa.ResourceManager()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 1
488, in __new__
visa_library = open_visa_library(visa_library)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 1
460, in open_visa_library
return cls(argument)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 9
6, in __new__
raise OSError('Could not open VISA library:\n' + '\n'.join(errs))
OSError: Could not open VISA library:

>>>
```

What could be my problem ?

I have tried to update the VISA path:

```
>>> rm = ResourceManager('C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ResourceManager' is not defined
>>> visalib = VisaLibrary('C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'VisaLibrary' is not defined
>>> rm = ResourceManager('C:/Program Files/Python35/Lib/site-packages')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ResourceManager' is not defined
>>> import visa
>>> rm = ResourceManager('C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ResourceManager' is not defined
>>>
```

Without any success

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544482/oserror-could-not-open-visa-library/35545129) first? or [official guideline](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#error-could-not-found-visa-library)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSError: Could not open VISA library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544482/oserror-could-not-open-visa-library)

Comment: I have tried your recommendations (updated my question, see above some more details). I don't see the problem yet

Comment: By the way, I have also checked the "official guideline" that you attached above. Do I also need to have the NI back-end installed before I start running PyVISA scripts ? My goal is to construct functions that will help me later configure my LAB instruments. None of my instruments is National Instruments device

Comment: The point is not if the instruments themselves are National Instruments, what matters here is who is the vendor of your GPIB card (or whatever bus your instruments use), and where is the VISA dll they provide to access it. Once you have the dll in place to act as a bridge between your PyVISA and the bus you can talk straight to your instruments according to the commands documented by their manufacturers.

Comment: I am not using GPIB or other cards to connect to my LAB Instruments for what I know there is no need for that. I plan on sending SCPI commands through TCP/IP. Do I still need to install the VISA DLL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyVISA is only Python wrapper for DLL which standard location is somewhere in Windows. For example at my PC is `C:\Windows\System32\visa64.dll`.

At my code i use `rm = visa.ResourceManager(C:\\Windows\\System32\\visa64.dll)`

Of course first time you have to get VISA library which is part of huge NI-VISA installation package which you can found here:
[NI-VISA Download Installer](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_nivisa.html#getting-nivisa)

Comment: Do I need to install the VISA DLL in order to use PyVISA while sending SCPI commands to my LAB instruments ?

Comment: Yes as i said PyVISA is only python interface for using NIVISA. From https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting.htmlyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting.html . _In order for PyVISA to work, you need to have a suitable backend. PyVISA includes a backend that wraps the National Instruments’s VISA library. However, you need to download and install the library yourself_

Comment: OK, Then what exactly do I need to download (and Install) in order to be able to send SCPI commands (via TCP/IP) ?

Comment: You should start with open this : https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_nivisa.html#getting-nivisa where you can find download links.

Comment: By the way, before installing the NI VISA I found out (by using "python -m visa info") that I have an NI backend (bundled with PyVISA) and it is Version 1.8 (Binary library: Not found). Does it still explain why did I fail in my first Step in PyVISA ?

Comment: Binary library is what you need. On my PC is output of `python -m visa info` Version: 1.8 (bundled with PyVISA)
      #1: C:\Windows\system32\visa32.dll:

Comment: Now I also have the visa32.dll as in your PC. I tried the "rm = visa.ResourceManager()" and now the error output was replaced with a certain warning "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py:1225:
VisaIOWarning: VI_WARN_CONFIG_NLOADED (1073676407): The specified configuration
either does not exist or could not be loaded. VISA-specified defaults will be us
ed.
  ret = library.viOpenDefaultRM(byref(session))" Are you familiar with this warning ? Is it OK ?

Comment: I have never met with this. But as you said it is just warning. Try if you can communicate with your device. Btw Here you can find the reason for this warning. http://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/VISA-error-with-Agilent-E3647A/td-p/104745